# Removing rollers from sliding door

Tags: sliding-glass-door

I'm trying to replace the rollers on this sliding door:

[image]

The first thing I noticed was the lack of adjustment holes. All I could find was a little dent as can be seen in this picture:

[image]

I was able to take out the door without lowering the rollers by just lifting it out.

I also managed to pull the inner part of the rollers out with sheer force (it was really rusty and falling apart anyway). I was however unable to pull out the case in which the rollers sit. I can see the bottom of a screw, as if it was screwed in from the top:

[image]

All of the information I find online tells me it should either come out without any screws or the screws should be accessible from the bottom.

What is the best way to remove the rollers including the case they sit in?

---

As requested, here are additional pictures of the whole roller slot and the remaining roller. It's hard to see but next to, what I assume is a rusty adjustment screw, you can see the end of a screw that presumably holds the roller frame.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please put in a picture of the entire roller slot; like the bottom one that you posted, but backed away a bit so we can see the whole thing? Also post a pic of the other side with (hopefully) the whole roller assembly still in place?

Answer (score 0):

This door is using crimped corners; the door frame is all one piece. There are adjusting screws for the rollers (photo 4) but the rollers are held in place by screws installed from the inside top of the frame. You will have to remove the glass panel to access them.